# Convert string date to new Date() object in Apps Script (javascript)

Tags: javascript, datetime, google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I'm making a [Google Timeline Chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/timeline) and it seems to require the dates in format:

```
new Date(2020, 09, 25, 01, 20); etc
```

However I'm drawing events from Calendar and they're coming in as:

```
[Thu Oct 05 06:20:00 GMT+10:04 2020]
```

I've tried to convert it in various ways, even forcefully concatenating strings to be "new Date(" + "yyyy, MM, dd..." etc but it doesn't work. It seems to *have* to be in that 'new Date()' format.

Any way this can be done?

EDIT: here is how I'm recieving the calendar events in Apps Script:

```
function getCalEvents(d) {
  var evs; 
  var i; 
  var out=[];
  evs=CalendarApp.getCalendarById('__________________________@group.calendar.google.com').getEventsForDay(d);
  for (i in evs) {
    out.push([evs[i].getTitle(),
              evs[i].getStartTime(),
              evs[i].getEndTime(),
              //Number(evs[i].getColor())
             ]);
  }
  return(out);
}
```

Comment: `[Thu Oct 05 06:20:00 GMT+10:04 2020]`  is not a js valid syntax

Comment: Your code?`````````````````​`````````````````

Comment: A value in brackets `[]` would typically indicate that it's an array. If that's the case, then you just need to get the appropriate element. `Thu Oct 05 06:20:00 GMT+10:04 2020` _is_ how Apps Script displays a [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) when logged. The 4 in the time zone is confusing–never seen that before.

Comment: @Diego these come into Apps Script via the CalendarApi in that format. It's actually a 2d array of calendar evets with the format: [[name, startdate (in the format I posted), enddate],[name, startdate, enddate], ]...etc

Comment: @JackNapier The format from api is a valid JavaScript date( regardless of how it looks like in the logger ).

Comment: @TheMaster yep I think it's a valid format but it doesn't work when I try and make a google graph. My code is essentially the first code section on this page (https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/timeline) and it doesn't seem to acccept the code format I've given it. It appears that it needs to be in 'new Date()' format to read it. I've updated the post with how I'm recieving the calendar events in Javascript.

Comment: If the problem occurs when trying to create a timeline chart, please add a [mcve]  showing how are you trying to create this chart.

Comment: @TheMaster, my apologies it now does work but only when I manually copy in the dates between quotes. Is there a way to get myArray into the Date slots for the dataTable? The below doesn't work.
var myArray = [Another test, Sun Sep 06 00:00:00 GMT+10:00 2020, Mon Sep 07 00:00:00 GMT+10:00 2020];
dataTable.addRows([
 ['Secretary of State', myArray[0].toString(), new Date(myArray[1]), new Date(myArray[2])]
]);

Comment: @Rubén I have a jsfiddle here (https://jsfiddle.net/frv0qL6y/1/). Obviously just random names/dates etc for privacy. Note that the chart works fine (the last two timeline items are just tests and also work fine). But the commented out sections are what I'm trying to link. The top is what the Calendar events print to the console as from the api, the bottom is what I'm trying to convert to, but it won't read it. Does that make sense?

Comment: @TheMaster I have a jsfiddle here if you have a moment (jsfiddle.net/frv0qL6y/1). Trying to turn the top commented out section into part of the array of chart dates at the bottom (also commented out).

Comment: 1. [Edit] to Provide [mcve]. What is the minimum I must  do to reproduce the error, you get? 2. `new Date()` returns a `date`.  `evs[i].getStartTime()` also returns a `date` same  format.  What you see in the logger means nothing. 3. Quote the exact text of the error. Or describe the error. What happens? What needs to happen? Like, chart loads a blank page instead of actual chart.

Comment: @TheMaster the linked jsfiddle in the above reply shows the issue (jsfiddle.net/frv0qL6y/1). The graph displays fine with the provided html/js. But I want to add further dates to the graph via the myEvents variable at the top (commented out). How can I format that 2d array so it's entries work in the graph?

Comment: Hi [edit] your question. You wrote `myEvents` based on what you saw. But like I said, What you saw in logger means nothing. Even if I did provide a  solution to work with your self declared `myEvents` variable(Which is syntactically wrong in the first place and therefore impossible), it won't solve the actual problem(Which probably has nothing  to do with  format of dates). So, show how you got `myEvents` from `getCalEvents`. Where is this running? Server or client? Also see https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/